# Is there a "All Children loaded" event in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am listening for the loaded event of a Page. That event fires first and then all the children fire their load event. I need an event that fires when ALL the children have loaded. Does that exist?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I hear you. I also am missing an out of the box solution in WPF for this.

Sometimes you want some code to be executed after all the child controls are loaded.

Put this in the constructor of the parent control

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => {code that should be executed after all children are loaded} ));
```

Helped me a few times till now.

Answer (score 12):

`Loaded` is the event that fires after all children have been `Initialized`. There is no `AfterLoad` event as far as I know. If you can, move the children's logic to the `Initialized` event, and then `Loaded` will occur after they have all been initialized.

See [MSDN - Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx).

Comment: This does not work if the parent needs to get the exact child's rendered size.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the event: ContentRendered.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Window_Lifetime_Events

Answer (score 0):

WPF cant provide that kind of an event since most of the time Data is determining whther to load a particular child to the VisualTree or not (for example UI elements inside a DataTemplate)

So if you can explain your scenario little more clearly we can find a solution specific to that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options (when content rendered):

this.LayoutUpdated += OnLayoutUpdated;

```
private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!isInitialized && this.ActualWidth != 0 && this.ActualHeight != 0)
                {
                    isInitialized = true;
                    // Logic here
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put inside your `xaml` component you want to wait for, a load event `Loaded="MyControl_Loaded"` like

```
<Grid Name="Main" Loaded="Grid_Loaded"...>
<TabControl Loaded="TabControl_Loaded"...>
<MyControl Loaded="MyControl_Loaded"...>
...
```

and in your `code`

```
bool isLoaded;

private void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   isLoaded = true;
}
```

Then, inside the Event triggers that have to do something but were triggering before having all components properly loaded, put `if(!isLoaded) return;` like

```
private void OnButtonChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!isLoaded) return;

    ... // code that must execute on trigger BUT after load
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I ended up doing something along these lines.. your milage may vary.

```
void WaitForTheKids(Action OnLoaded)
{
  // After your children have been added just wait for the Loaded
  // event to fire for all of them, then call the OnLoaded delegate

  foreach (ContentControl child in Canvas.Children)
  {
    child.Tag = OnLoaded; // Called after children have loaded
    child.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(child_Loaded);
  }
}
internal void child_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var cc = sender as ContentControl;
  cc.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(child_Loaded);

  foreach (ContentControl ctl in Canvas.Children)
  {
    if (!ctl.IsLoaded)
    {
      return;
    }
  }
  ((Action)cc.Tag)();
}
```